# height overflow auto doesn't work in my case

Tags: css

demo http://www.bootply.com/pK8YqTHQXr

I want to add hover to the block to make appear the 3 Images but now I seem stuck at the overflow thing. The lower part of the box didn't wrap within the main block. Why?

I tried `height 100%` it become even worse.

Comment: you want to add red box inside your main box(bordered one) ?????

Comment: Something like this? http://www.bootply.com/coQIxjRN62

Comment: or something like this http://www.bootply.com/ukAgZY9WBu

Comment: @rajeshkakawat pls post as answer, yes that's what I want, what changes u made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
.box{
  height:auto; 
}
```

LINK TO CHECK http://www.bootply.com/ukAgZY9WBu